# Brake pads excessively worn on one wheel one

Tags: brakes, abs

The brake pads on the rear right caliper are wearing stupidly fast on my '06 Saab TiD. In 10k miles the rear right had gone down from 10mm to 4mm, whilst the left rear have only gone down 1mm.

The front pads have gone down 3mm only in 25k miles.

It basically looks like most braking is on the rear right caliper, which is odd as the imbalance wasn't reported in the MOT test last ear (the next one is due in November).

- sliding pins clean and greased
- calipers clean
- pistons retracting smoothly and gators intact
- brake fluid (replaced last year) checked for contamination (less than 1%, so nearly new)
- no warning lights and nothing comes up on the ODB scanner
- pads worn evenly - see pic, pads are reversed i.e. right pads on the left
- the car does not steer to the left or right when braking

I talked to a mechanic who thinks it might be ABS unit: is there a way to test it? Other options?

[image]

Comment: Check the flexible to that caliper - it could be holding pressure to the caliper and wearing the pads...

Comment: Another thing to check would be the rubber hose to the caliper. It's fairly rare but they can degrade and function as a check valve.

Comment: I don't know what kind of checks as they both look fine - dry, no cracks, unusual bends or other. I moved them around as I removed the calipers and there was nothing unusual

Comment: @GabeWisneski I think I wrote what you wrote just a few hours earlier...

Comment: You have a sticking caliper on that side, replace it.

Comment: @Solar Mike as long as the op reads it and checks it it's all good

Comment: @Solar Mike I don't actually know if you meant I wrote it first or you did. Sorry, if you did, I didn't think I'd miss it if yours was first.

Comment: @GabeWisneski I posted 5 hours before you did... Not sure how you missed it.

Comment: Also, for the op, a good way to test if the rubber hose is bad is to do the following. On the affected wheel try to compress the caliper by wedging a pry bar between the pad and the caliper and attempt to force it down. If you can with not much effort it's neither the line nor caliper. If you do struggle with it try cracking the bleeder. If it now moves easily it's most likely the rubber line, if not the caliper is most likely seized or close to it. You could also remove the caliper and try this test with a standard caliper compressor or equivalent. You can test another wheel for a comparison.

Comment: Anyways, best of luck.

Comment: @GabeWisneski To replace the pads I had to remove the calipers and push (screw) the pistons in otherwise the new pads wouldn't fit. Again, pistons slid without problems. Yesterday I also checked the brake fluid in case it had deteriorated since last year (e.g. for a leak) and that's fine too. I'm wondering if there might be an issue with a speed sensor sending a bad signal to the ABS